# HTML Web Form from XSLT and POST user data as XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I am facing one problem. I need to build a form submission system which is as followed -

1. The browser renders the web form from an xslt file.
2. The user fills up the web form and clicks on submit.
3. The browser creates a xml for the filled up form.
4. The browser posts the data to the server.

Can anyone help me with exisiting libraries to do that? (I tried Altova Stylevison but have some disadvantages).

Comment: Can anyone help me with exisiting libraries to do that? (I tried Altova Stylevison but have some disadvantages).

--do you want an IDE/Editor to write XSLT? what do you mean my existing library?

Comment: No, not IDE. Look, the server will send you one xslt and one empty xml file. The browser will render the xslt and show one html form. The user will enter values in the form and when submit button is clicked the user updated form will update the empty xml file, and this xml file will be posted to the server. I want a library that does the things that happens on the browser side. There is one library called altova SPS, but it is not free of cost :(    .

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I'm not aware of one such library which does this for me. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn XSLT [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp) article says how you can transform xml to html. Using this approach you can display the result in the browser and collect the data and construct the xml. once xml is constructed you can use the same tutorial to send the data back to server using Ajax (use POST instead of GET).